# Payments for website where goal must be reached before users are charged

Tags: paypal

what payment solution should I sign up for to implement payments where goal must be reached before users are charged? For example teespring.com uses this solution. Users pay, money is reserved in their account, but they are charged only if the goal is reached. If not, money never leaves their account. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have a number of options here. If you would like to accept payments strictly using credit cards, Authorize.net is a good choice. Here you would use Authorize.net's AIM API to authorize but not capture payments. You would store authorizations and commit captures only if your goal was reached. The API calls here are AuthOnly, followed by AuthCapture.

See: http://developer.authorize.net/api/aim/

If you would like to accept payment using PayPal, I recommend you use the Express Checkout API. Here, you would authorize but not capture payments again, and only capture once your goal was reached. The API calls here are DoAuthorization and Capture.

See: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here are some more resources for you: 

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoAuthorization_API_Operation_NVP/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/